# Docker with Alpine Linux with Ioncube Loader and PHP 5.6 / 7

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

I tried two different Docker images alpine:edge with PHP7.0.10 (ionCube Loader Beta8) and alpine:3.4 with PHP 5.6.25 (ionCube 5.1.2, `ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so`).

I figured so far that PHP7 needs to be compiled with thread safety to work with the ionCube beta, thats why I wanted to try it with PHP5.6 but also here a `php -v` fails with:

```
Failed loading /etc/php5/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so:  Error relocating /etc/php5/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so: __strndup: symbol not found
PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2016 14:36:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: can it be related to alpines usage of musl instead of glibc? https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10782897